# Apache POI Add Image to Sheet of XSSFWorkbook Android

Tags: android, apache-poi

Sorry for disturbance. I have a question for you ,i need a little help about Excel XSSFWorkbook adding a JPG image to the Sheet. I have the code below

```
String picturePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyImages/Signature_1582216915190.jpg";
        File iconFile = new File(picturePath);
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(iconFile);
        CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
        Drawing drawing = sheetTAF.createDrawingPatriarch();
        ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
        anchor.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.MOVE_AND_RESIZE);
        int pictureIndex = workbook.addPicture(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream), Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
        anchor.setCol1(0);
        anchor.setRow1(56); // same row is okay
        anchor.setRow2(56);
        anchor.setCol2(1);
        Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIndex);
        pict.resize();
```

My Intention is to put an image Signature_1582216915190.jpg to my excel sheet but i got no excel after adding above portion of code ,when removing the code works fine.
Can anyone help how can i add an image to excel workbook or can help with the fix of above snapshot? Thank you in advance